# How to write mysql query to combine in single variable

Tags: mysql

I have a table having children and a parent_name
I want to select all the children of a parent and add them in a single variable like:

```
Select children as all_children, parent_name from children_table
```

if i echo in php:

```
echo "$parent_name children names are $all_children";
```

it will show as

```
Tom children names are Jim,Foo,Li
```

all_children need to have values from multiple rows

`groupBy parent_name` option is not working for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use group_concate(children) as all_children
which works for me